# Wordpress - can't get rid of malware - can I use .htaccess to restrict?

Tags: wordpress, malware

I'm not a newbie to WordPress, but definitely a newb to getting hacked.  I am trying to remove some malware from a site but it just keeps coming back.

I am using wordfence to find malware and I keep getting a single file back as a malicious file citing Backdoor:PHP/reval.C.3102 as the cause. The file is in wp-content and named "type.php"  I can delete with wordfence and it just comes back. I can also delete in cpanel file manager and it will re-appear within minutes. Is there any way I can block the writing of this file with an .htaccess file or something? Has anyone experienced this before and has other recommendations?

Thanks!

Comment: The file is a symptom of the problem. Blocking the file does not fix the problem; it's like putting a band-aid on a bullet wound.